# How can I add multiple header files recursively in .modulemap?

Tags: clang, cocoapods, module-map

for example, this .modulemap works:

```
framework module MySDK {
  umbrella header "MySDK-umbrella.h"
  header "inc/header1.h"
  header "inc/header2.h"
  header "inc/header3.h"
  ...

  export *
  module * { export * }
}
```

but this one does not:

```
framework module MySDK {
  umbrella header "MySDK-umbrella.h"
  header "inc/*.h"

  export *
  module * { export * }
}
```

So how can I add multiple header files recursively in .modulemap?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend investigating using `umbrella "Headers"` instead of `umbrella header "MySDK-umbrella.h"` for a case like this.

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#umbrella-directory-declaration